# NullPointer exception on field that is retrieved on the query

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-field, exception

During a test, a case is inserted, its owner is a queue, and a custom field, which references another custom object, is left blank on purpose (for the test).

When the code is run, there's a condition like the following:

```
if (record.CustomField__c != null) {
    // do something
}
```

At the conditional line I'm getting the exception, even though the field is included on the query (this particular conditional is being run on the Case trigger too, and it works just fine on the trigger test class).

I know that `record.CustomField__c` points to nothing (no reference), and because of this the conditional result should be `false` (since `null` is not different from `null`). Shouldn't this work? How can I verify that the reference field is blank without putting this on a SOQL condition?

---

Edit:

On the debug logs I see the following when the code is executed on the trigger context:

> 09:50:45:796 USER_DEBUG [73]|DEBUG|(Case:{Id=5002F000002VeDvQAK, IsDeleted=false, CaseNumber=00118772, ContactId=0032F000009Vi2mQAC, AccountId=0012F00000D9sKFQAZ...

And then, when I execute the method outside the trigger context (the method accepts a list of cases), this is what appears:

> 09:50:46:409 USER_DEBUG [73]|DEBUG|(Case:{Id=5002F000002VeDvQAK})

Before passing the record to the method I'm querying it, and the proof that the record isn't null is that it contains a valid Id.

On the trigger, the code looks like this:

```
public void runThing () {
    runThing(Trigger.new, Trigger.isInsert);
}

public void runThing (List<Case> records, Boolean isInsert) {
    for (Case record : records) {
        // here's the check that throws the exception, even though the record is not null
        if (record.CustomField__c != null) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // ... do something else here
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to run the code like this:

```
// 'unassigned_cases' is a query result on the Case table
// and 'true' is passed so the code is executed like if this
// was being run in a insert trigger (the exception is 
// preventing it from being run)
new CaseTriggerHandler().runAssignmentRules(unassigned_cases, true);
```

---

Second Edit:

After trying some modifications to the code, I've noticed that using `String.isBlank()` works for determining if the field is empty. If I negate this method result, though, the null pointer error persists.

```
String.isBlank(record.CustomField__c)  // true
!String.isBlank(record.CustomField__c) // System.NullPointerException...
```

Another approach I've tried:

```
System.debug(String.isBlank(record.CustomReference__c));
Boolean doesntHaveReference = String.isBlank(record.CustomReference__c);
System.debug(doesntHaveReference);
if (!doesntHaveReference) // null pointer here!
    continue;
```

Using `isNotBlank` is also throwing a null pointer exception:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(record.CustomReference__c))
```

Comment: Start throwing debugs in there. That error should only be possible if `record` or `records` is null (if the error line were off by 1). Verify your collection exists before looping over it, and that your record exists before accessing its values. Also use that to pinpoint where your execution actually stops, since it still doesn't seem like a line that could be the ultimate culprit.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The thing is I have a debug right after the case list is retrieved from the query. It is right before calling the method, and inside the method I have another debug on that same list, and they show the exact same thing on both (the second debug line I've posted).

Comment: And what happens if you add a `debug` right inside your `if` block? At the end of the `for` loop? End of the method? That line is not the right one if `record` is not null.

Comment: Right inside the for, if I add a `System.debug(record);` before the condition, the record appears on the log with its Id only, just like the second debug line on the original post. If I put the debug inside the condition, or at the end of the loop, they won't even be displayed, because the exception is happening on the condition line.

Comment: FYI there is a `String.isNotBlank` method. Regardless this seems like a platform bug. What API Version are you using?

Comment: Both classes are on API 39, and the trigger handler class is on 41. I'll bump those two and see what happens. I was about to do that when I've seen your comment.

Comment: I can't repo your `String.IsBlank` example on cs14. Would be interested in looking at a self contained example of this behavior. Agree with adrian, seems like a platform bug from whats here so far.

Comment: @AdrianLarson neither bumping those numbers up or changing to `isNotBlank` worked. They both result in the null pointer exception on the condition line.

Comment: You should not be able to produce `null` values for any of these `Boolean` results. File a case with support. Definitely a bug.

Comment: This is definitely weird. The method itself is on the trigger handler class. I'll try to move it to another class, and see what happens. If I can't get it working, I'll try to reach support. Thank you guys for your comments, and for letting me know that I'm not getting insane :)